# Profiles issues - Mozilla Firefox VS Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, user-profiles

Till now I was working with Google Chrome with different profiles, each one synchronized with a different gmail account.

I would like to move to Mozilla Firefox. I saw that firefox has also profiles, but it seems quite different from chrome.

My questions:

- Is it possible to open a different profile easily from another profile, as it is in chrome?
- Is it possible to sync a profile with gmail account?
- Is it possible to add an icon to each profile, to facilitate its usage?

Comment: Firefox does of course _not_ sync to Google. But what do you mean with the first question? Perhaps something like right-clicking on a link and selecting _Open in profile XYZ_?

Comment: I chrome there is a small icon on the right side of the address-bar, which opens a dialog box with a list of all profiles, and sync status. From there one can open another profile directly. This is what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox there are profiles. The profile manager may be opened on startup by starting Firefox with [c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEGG2.png)

Then you can have multiple profiles, with their own setup, accounts saved, etc.

To run a profile, start the profile manager again or provide the profile name as an argument:

c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -P my-another-profile